# HTTPS connections in android with firebase performance monitoring

Tags: android, ssl, firebase, httpsurlconnection, firebase-performance

I have just integrated firebase performance monitoring in my android app.

In our infrastructure, sometimes we need to connect to a local dev machine over https, and I use this piece of code to avoid ssl certificate checking when connecting to a local machine

```
private SSLSocketFactory getFakeSSLContext() {
        final SSLContext sslContext;

        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
                // Not implemented
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
                // Not implemented
            }
        }};

        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

            // Create all-trusting host name verifier
            final HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = (hostname, session) -> true;
            // Install the all-trusting host verifier
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);

            return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            LogHelper.e("error creating fake ssl context", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

obviously we do not use it in production :)

The problem is that since I introduced firebase perfomance monitoring plugin, this does not work anymore, and I get this error [image]

As you can see in the highlighted 2 lines, it looks like it does something inside the HttpsUrlConnection implementation, and I think that is the cause of the problem. I tried to use `FirebasePerformance.getInstance().setPerformanceCollectionEnabled(false);`
on my application's onCreate method but the problem is still there.
How can I make untrusted https connection with firebase performance plugin installed?

thank you

Comment: Firebase Performance Monitoring doesn't do anything *inside* HttpsURLConnection.  But it does *wrap* any calls you make to it so that it can measure the app's use of it.  Are you absolutely certain that if you remove the plugin, everything starts working again?

Comment: yes, I am totally sure, I double checked it because I couldn't believe it

Comment: Is there any chance you can provide a bare minimal project that duplicates the problem?  I will get the Firebase team to look at it.

Comment: I will get back at office on monday, I'll provide a sample project to reproduce the issue. If it can be of any help I think it's just enough to create a request using an HttpsUrlConnection, and call on the connection object the method setSSLSocketFactory() passing as parameter the result of the code snippet provided in the question. Obviously in a project with firebase performance monitor plugin installed

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this with my own code.  Are you able to provide an example?

Comment: Hi Doug, I will try to provide you a sample as soon as I can, I'm a little bit busy at office these days, but I will do my best to contribute understanding the problem